# Why do we need OPA gatekeeper?

Tags: kubernetes, controls, open-policy-agent

I am trying to understand what is OPA(open policy agent)  and its use-cases and I'm in the basic stage . When I was reading an opa article I got to know about the OPA Gatekeeper but I don't have a clear understanding about why we need this OPA gatekeeper? can we use this for auditing all kinds of policies in kubernetes like Pod scheduling, Cluster placement ,Authorization etc.or is it only specific for  kubernetes admission control phase ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs:

> Kubernetes allows decoupling policy decisions from the API server by
>   means of admission controller webhooks to intercept admission requests
>   before they are persisted as objects in Kubernetes. **Gatekeeper** was
>   created to enable users to customize admission control via
>   configuration, not code and to bring awareness of the cluster’s state,
>   not just the single object under evaluation at admission time.
>   **Gatekeeper** is a customizable admission webhook for Kubernetes that
>   enforces policies executed by the Open Policy Agent (OPA).
>
> **Validating Admission Control**
>
> Once all the Gatekeeper components have been installed in your
>   cluster, the API server will trigger the Gatekeeper admission webhook
>   to process the admission request whenever a resource in the cluster is
>   created, updated, or deleted.
>
> **Audit**
>
> The audit functionality enables periodic evaluations of replicated
>   resources against the Constraints enforced in the cluster to detect
>   pre-existing misconfigurations. Gatekeeper stores audit results as
>   violations listed in the status field of the relevant Constraint. By default, the audit will request each resource from the Kubernetes API during each cycle of the audit.

And to answer your questions in short: Gatekeeper is designed to take care of both the admission scenario and the audit of the replicated resources.

Sources:

- [OPA Gatekeeper: Policy and Governance for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/08/06/opa-gatekeeper-policy-and-governance-for-kubernetes/)
- [Gatekeeper on GitHub](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper#gatekeeper)

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer and I’ll definitely read these sources too. Another thing that I got from all this information is we can use Gatekeeper only for admission control in kubernetes (Please make me correct if I'm wrong). And I wanted to know,  other than that is there any relationship between  Gatekeeper and the other OPA use cases in kubernetes like Workload Placement ,Pod scheduling etc ?

Comment: I suggest going through the listed sources as they will explain in detail way better than I possibly could. But to answer your additional question in short: admission control is not the only functionality of Gatekeeper. It also takes care of auditing and provides "constraints" and "constraints templates". And `Gatekeeper is a customizable admission webhook for Kubernetes that enforces policies executed by the Open Policy Agent (OPA)` is the general relationship between these two.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and resources .Now I understand the point and it helped me a lot. thank you.